# Authenticating with BPIPE Service from remote machine Rblpapi

Tags: r, bloomberg, rblpapi

I work in an environment in which I have a windows PC with a Bloomberg terminal, but I do most of my analytical work on a remote server via ssh since I prefer a linux environment. I also have access to a B-PIPE server and I am trying to figure out how (and if) I can connect/authenticate with the B-PIPE server from the server I am ssh'ed into. Obviously, Rblpapi works out of the box on my windows machine, but that uses the desktop API rather than BPIPE.

On my windows PC where the terminal is running, I can do the following to authenticate with BPIPE:

```
library(Rblpapi)
con <- blpConnect(host = "ip.address.of.bpipe.server", appName = "my.bpipe.app.name")
blpAuthenticate()
```

However, I believe this works because bloomberg is somehow able to figure out that it's me, given that I am running my terminal on the windows PC. How would I establish the connection on the remote server so that bloomberg knows that it's me? Would I specify uuid from my terminal and ip address of the windows pc that I am running the terminal on? Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you asked support?

Comment: I have, but I have not gotten a clear answer (probably because I am not asking the question correctly) - and the bloomberg help desk doesn't help with BPIPE issues

Answer (score 0):

Should always read the documentation carefully...this resolves the issue:

```
library(Rblpapi)
con <- blpConnect(host = "ip.address.of.bpipe.server", appName = "my.bpipe.app.name")
id <- blpAuthenticate(con = con, host = "ip.address.of.bpipe.server")
bdp("SPX Index", "PX_LAST", con = con, verbose = TRUE, identity = id)
```